# split multi valued dynamic fields in Solr Data import handler

Tags: dynamic, solr, field, dataimporthandler

Is it possible to split multivalued dynamic fields?

Schema:

`<dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>`

DIH-config:

```
<field column="*_s" splitBy="\|" />
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any help is appriciated!

UPDATE inspired on the comment

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
   url="jdbc:sqlserver://${dataimporter.request.sqlserver};databaseName=${dataimporter.request.sqlcatelog};responseBuffering=adaptive;"
   user="${dataimporter.request.sqluser}"
   password="${dataimporter.request.sqlpassword}"
   readOnly="true" batchSize="500"/>

  <script><![CDATA[
    function SplitDynamicColumn(row, context) {
      var fields = context.getAllEntityFields();

      // find dynamic columns with 'splitBy' rule
      for (var f = 0; f < fields.size(); f++) {
        var field = fields.get(f);
        var columnMask = field.get('column');

        if (columnMask.contains('*') && field.containsKey('splitBy')) {
          var columnNameRegex = columnMask.replace('*', '\\w+');

          var columns = row.keySet().toArray();

          // find columns that match mask
          for (var c = 0; c < columns.length; c++) {
            var columnName = columns[c];
            if (columnName.matches(columnNameRegex)) {

               // split column value
               var value = row.get(columnName);
               if (value !== null) {
                 var arr = new java.util.ArrayList();
                 var sp = value.split(field.get('splitBy'));
                 for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
                   arr.add(sp[i]);
                 }
                 row.put(columnName, arr);
               }
             }
          }
        }
      }
      return row;
    }
  ]]></script>

  <document name="pages">
    <entity name="pages" transformer="RegexTransformer,script:SplitDynamicColumn" query="EXEC A_STORED_PROCEDURE">
      <field column="*_s" splitBy="\|" />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Answer (score 1):

splitBy is a flag for the RegexTransformer. Make sure you have [the transformers](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Transformer) sets on that entity properly.

However, more importantly, I do not believe DIH will support the wildcard the way you define it. DIH does support wildcard mapping by trying to match field name to schema name, but that does not allow you to define any transformations.

You may just not be able to combine those two features. One way to get around it is by writing your own custom transformer that does not require an definition with the attribute to run.